# Associate Dockerfile language with all Dockerfiles in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, dockerfile

What I want to do is tell Visual Studio Code to associate all files containing the word "Dockerfile" in their filename with the Dockerfile language to get the syntax highlighting. According to [this site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/user_ed/2015/10/24/what-languages-are-supported-for-visual-studio-code/) the language is just called "Dockerfile", so I added the following entry to settings.json:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*Dockerfile*": "Dockerfile"
}
```

But all that happened was that now even the standard Dockerfiles are no longer associated with their respective language. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language identifier for Dockerfile is a lower-case `dockerfile` as stated on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers. Hence, you need to adjust your snippet as follows:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*Dockerfile*": "dockerfile"
}
```